# Morphological Image Processing using C Language

Tags: c, image-processing

[Download or See Image Here](https://github.com/Arjuna-17/Mini-Project/blob/Arjuna/MorphologicalImageProcessing/image.pbm)

The problem statement is that I need to perform dilation and erosion on a binary image and using a structure element of dimension given by the user typically a 1D or 2D array and it can be square matrix(n X n) or rectangle matrix (m X n) where m, n can be even or odd integers.

This is morphological image processing using C language.

I implemented the following code, but I am not getting output as expected. Can any one tell me my mistake?

I am taking origin as a // 2 and b // 2 of structuring element which is order of a X b.
The following is my main function in image processing.

```
#include "DEOC.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])<br>
{
    FILE *fp, *op1, *op2, *op3, *op4;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    op1 = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    op2 = fopen(argv[3], "wb");
    op3 = fopen(argv[4], "wb");
    op4 = fopen(argv[5], "wb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is a problem in file opening!!! Please check again!!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    int i, j, col, row, x, y, temp;
    char ch1, ch2;

    fscanf(fp, "%c%c", &ch1, &ch2);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &col, &row);

    fprintf(op1, "%c%c\n", ch1, ch2);
    fprintf(op1, "%d %d\n", col, row);

    fprintf(op2, "%c%c\n", ch1, ch2);
    fprintf(op2, "%d %d\n", col, row);

    fprintf(op3, "%c%c\n", ch1, ch2);
    fprintf(op3, "%d %d\n", col, row);

    fprintf(op4, "%c%c\n", ch1, ch2);
    fprintf(op4, "%d %d\n", col, row);

    int *img, *dialated_img, *eroted_img, *opened, *closed, *structure;
    img = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
    dialated_img = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
    eroted_img = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
    opened = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
    closed = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter x: - ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter y: - ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    structure = (int *)malloc(x * y * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            *(structure + i * y + j) = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Used Structure is: -\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(structure + i * y + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp);
            *(img + i * col + j) = temp;
            *(dialated_img + i * col + j) = temp;
            *(eroted_img + i * col + j) = temp;
            *(opened + i * col + j) = temp;
            *(closed + i * col + j) = temp;
        }
    }

    dialation(img, dialated_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
    erosion(img, eroted_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
    opening(img, opened, structure, row, col, x, y);
    closing(img, closed, structure, row, col, x, y);

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            fprintf(op1, "%d", *(dialated_img + i * col + j));
            fprintf(op2, "%d", *(eroted_img + i * col + j));
            fprintf(op3, "%d", *(opened + i * col + j));
            fprintf(op4, "%d", *(closed + i * col + j));
        }
        fprintf(op1, "\n");
        fprintf(op2, "\n");
        fprintf(op3, "\n");
        fprintf(op4, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(op1);
    fclose(op2);
    fclose(op3);
    fclose(op4);

    return 0;
}
```

The DEOC.h file is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dialation(int *img, int *dialation_img, int *structure, int row, int col, int x, int y)
{
    int s = x / 2;
    int a = y / 2;

    for (int i = s; i < row - s; i++)
    {
        for (int j = a; j < col - a; j++)
        {
            if (*(img + i * col + j) == 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int w = -1 * s; w <= s; w++)
                {
                    for (int q = -1 * a; q <= a; q++)
                    {
                        if (*(structure + (w + s) * y + (q + a)) == 1)
                        {
                            if (*(img + (i + w) * col + (j + q)) == 1)
                            {
                                *(dialation_img + i * col + j) = 2;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (*(dialation_img + i * col + j) == 2)
            {
                *(dialation_img + i * col + j) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void erosion(int *img, int *erosion_img, int *structure, int row, int col, int x, int y)
{
    int s = x / 2;
    int a = y / 2;

    for (int i = s; i < row - s; i++)
    {
        for (int j = a; j < col - a; j++)
        {
            for (int w = -1 * s; w <= s; x++)
            {
                for (int q = -1 * a; q <= a; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (*(structure + (w + s) * y + (q + a)) == 1)
                        {
                            if (*(img + (i + w) * col + (j + q)) == 0)
                            {
                                *(erosion_img + i * col + j) = 2;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (*(erosion_img + i * col + j) == 2)
            {
                *(erosion_img + i * col + j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void opening(int *img, int *opened_img, int *structure, int row, int col, int x, int y)
{
    erosion(img, opened_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
    dialation(img, opened_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
}

void closing(int *img, int *closed_img, int *structure, int row, int col, int x, int y)
{
    dialation(img, closed_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
    erosion(img, closed_img, structure, row, col, x, y);
}
```

I am trying to use it but it is not executing properly.

Comment: “but it is not executing properly” is a very vague problem statement. If you are more explicit about the problem, it will be much easier to answer. Basically you are asking us to run your code and find out what your problem is, before being able to help you fix the problem. Not many people will want to do this. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: ok I added some more information. Thank you for your response.

Comment: This appears to be a custom file format. Would you be able to provide a sample file that allows the issue to be reproduced?

Comment: thank you I added a link to the image file